# including '\' in strtok() in C

Tags: c, tokenize, delimiter, strtok, backslash

Hello I am parsing text and using strtok() to do so. I am not sure how to include a '\' in my delimiters as C sees anything after this char as code.

```
char delims[] = "\n !@#$%^&*)(_+-=][}{|:;'<>?,./""";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Escape it with a \? It also seems like many of your other things in that list also need to be escaped.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: The double quotes need to be escaped. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Fixed tags for you: \ is *back* slash. Forward slash is /.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use an escape sequence for this. Escape sequences always start with a '`\`', and have one or more characters that follow.

In your example, you're after '`\\`'.

See this article on MSDN for more information about escape sequences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept an answer (green tick) when you've found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char delims[] = "\n !@#$%^&*)(_+-=][}{|:;'<>?,./\"\\";
```